# Страничная организация памяти

Tags: память, ос, paging

Возникли трудности в понимании представления памяти.

**Задача:** 
Допустим, у вас есть архитектура с 32 битным логическим адресным пространством (т. е. логический адрес – 32 битное число). Архитектура использует 2 уровневую таблицу страниц, т. е. логический адрес разбивается на три участка: два индекса в таблице страниц и смещение (ровно так как это было в примере на слайдах).

Причем в таблицах на каждом уровне таблицы страниц ровно по 1024 записи (соответственно, на индекс в каждой таблице уходит по 10 бит), и вы используете страницы размером в 4096 байт (т. е. смещение – это 12 битное число, нетрудно заметить, что вместе получаем 32 бита = 10 + 10 + 12).

**Внимание вопрос (конкретно на него отвечать не нужно) :** если процесс использует только два участка логического адресного пространства: 4MB, начиная с логического адреса 0x0, и 2MB, начиная с адреса 0xbfe00000, то сколько записей в корневой таблице будут указывать на таблицы следующего уровня?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Моё понимание этой задачи** (просьба указать и исправить ошибки):

1) Lvl1 и Lvl0 index занимают по 10 бит, Offset 12.

2) Каждая таблица обозначенная Level Num вмещает в себя 1024 записи чего-то и индексов по 10 бит (в схеме указал только 10 бит в размере каждой ячейки. Подразумевается, что там ещё + n бит). Значит индексы занимают 1024*10/8 байт, что равно 1280 байт. Всего таблица занимает 4096 байт, значит какие-то остальные данные размером 2816 байт хранятся в таблице.

3)На этом пункте ступор. Не понимаю как связать эти 4MB и логические адреса с информацией выше.

**Прошу объяснить принцип работы памяти и дать пояснение к решению задания. Конкретно решение задания прошу не писать, т.к. моя цель понять, а потом уже самому дать ответ.**

Comment: Не понимаю ваших вычислений. вернее к чему они относятся. про размер таблицы у вас в описании задачи не сказано ничего и ее не надо мерить в байтах вообще. Надо считать сколько памяти может описать одна таблица. Одна запись lvl0 должна описывать одну страницу, т.е. 4096 байт, значит целая таблица lvl0 может описать 1024*4096 байт памяти, т.е. 4 Мб. В корневой таблице понадобится столько записей, сколько таблиц lvl0 вам надо будет использовать.

Comment: Кстати, сами таблицы занимают не 4096 байт. Например в процессорах x86 в 32 битном режиме одна таблица занимает 32Кб, 1024 записи по 32 бита. Но к вашей задаче это отношения не имеет, так как сами страницы лежат в физической памяти. А необходимость описать в таблицах саму память таблиц, для доступа к ней ОС явно за рамками задачи, потому что вопросы создания самих таблиц в задаче не затрагиваются. Если бы их надо было учитывать, то в задаче было бы сказано какого размера одна запись таблицы lvl0

Comment: @Mike кажется я Вас понял. Спасибо, сейчас сам отвечу на свой вопрос.

Comment: Да, все верно. только у вас задача простая. В идеале надо учитывать, что одна таблица страниц (lvl0) описывает неразрывные 4 Мб виртуальной памяти. А значит если бы нам сказали, что у нас 6 Мб в виде трех регионов по далеким друг от друга смещениям, скажем 0, 0x0fe00000 и 0xbfe00000 то нам бы уже понадобилось бы 3 таблицы. А еще можно придумать задачу, скажем надо выделить всего 8Кб по адресу 0x3FF000, то нам бы потребовалось целых две таблицы, потому что первая из них накроет регион только до 3FFFFF, в котором будет только первая страница, а вторая будет 400000 и войдет в другую таблицу

Comment: но в вашей задаче у адресов заведомо много нулей в конце, так что они гарантированно начинаются на разделах описываемых одной таблицей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к. таблиц у нас всего две по условию задачи, то нам нужно узнать сколько требуется указывающих на таблицу Lvl 0 записей в корневой таблице (она же Lvl 1).

**Сколько описывает таблица Lvl 0 ?** В каждой таблице по 1024 записи, каждая запись описывает одну страницу в 4096 байт. 1024*4096 = 4 Мб.

**Нам нужно описать 6 Мб по условию задачи**. Если одна таблица Lvl 0 может описать 4Мб, то нам нужно как минимум 2 таких таблицы. Значит, нужно две записи из корневой таблицы Lvl 1.

Спасибо [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike) за пояснение в комментариях насчёт моей интерпретации задачи и её решения:

> Кстати, сами таблицы занимают не 4096 байт. Например в процессорах x86
>   в 32 битном режиме одна таблица занимает 32Кб, 1024 записи по 32 бита.
>   Но к вашей задаче это отношения не имеет, так как сами страницы лежат
>   в физической памяти. А необходимость описать в таблицах саму память
>   таблиц, для доступа к ней ОС явно за рамками задачи, потому что
>   вопросы создания самих таблиц в задаче не затрагиваются. Если бы их
>   надо было учитывать, то в задаче было бы сказано какого размера одна
>   запись таблицы lvl0